# How to implement setup and teardown approach for my Behave Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-behave

I am trying to implement setup/teardown approach using fixtures for my Behave project.

I am having trouble getting it to work, here is my code which I have kept inside environment.py

import logging as logger
import pdb

def before_feature(context,feature):
all_tags = feature.tags
if '@x' in all_tags:
context.x = True
logger.info("Before feature")
logger.info("")

def after_feature(context, feature):
logger.info("After feature")
logger.info("")

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
logger.info("Before Scenario")
logger.info("")
if scenario.name == 'User has logged into Jenkins process with valid Credentials':
# setup for the scenario
# call()
pass

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Nothing is printing when I run the code, and I expected output for validation

Answer (score 0):

There's an existing framework with a mode that fully combines `selenium` with `behave`. https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/ReadMe.md (You could learn a lot from that, or even use it.)

If you are trying to define setup/teardown methods, you can use these built-in `behave` methods, which should exist in an `environment.py` file:

- `before_all(context)`
- `before_feature(context, feature)`
- `before_scenario(context, scenario)`
- `before_step(context, step)`
- `after_step(context, step)`
- `after_scenario(context, scenario)`
- `after_feature(context, feature)`
- `after_all(context)`

With [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), those methods are defined here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/behave/behave_sb.py and then imported into the `environment.py` file here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/features/environment.py

In combination with **steps** files, such as https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/features/steps/calculator.py and/or https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/sbase/steps.py, you can then easily create tests like this:

```
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the RealWorld App

  Scenario: Verify RealWorld App (log in / sign out)
    Given Open "seleniumbase.io/realworld/login"
    And Clear Session Storage
    When Type "demo_user" into "#username"
    And Type "secret_pass" into "#password"
    And Do MFA "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG" into "#totpcode"
    Then Assert exact text "Welcome!" in "h1"
    And Highlight "img#image1"
    And Click 'a:contains("This Page")'
    And Save screenshot to logs
    When Click link "Sign out"
    Then Assert element 'a:contains("Sign in")'
    And Assert text "You have been signed out!"
```

When run with `behave`, you'll see the following output:

```bash
> behave realworld.feature 

Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the RealWorld App # realworld.feature:1

  Scenario: Verify RealWorld App (log in / sign out)  # realworld.feature:3
    Given Open the RealWorld Login Page               # steps/real_world.py:4
    When Login to the RealWorld App                   # steps/real_world.py:11
    Then Assert exact text "Welcome!" in "h1"         # steps/real_world.py:89
    When Highlight element "img#image1"               # steps/real_world.py:19
    And Click element 'a:contains("This Page")'       # steps/real_world.py:29
    Then Save a screenshot to the logs                # steps/real_world.py:49
    When Click link "Sign out"                        # steps/real_world.py:39
    Then Assert element 'a:contains("Sign in")'       # steps/real_world.py:55
    And Assert text "You have been signed out!"       # steps/real_world.py:79
   ✅ Scenario Passed!

--- LogPath: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/integrations/behave/features/latest_logs/
1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
9 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m2.813s
```